# Merging CSV table rows according to the first column in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, merge

I am trying to figure out how to merge CSV table rows according to the first column in bash, e.g.:

```
date,added,deleted
2016-01-20,16,10
2016-02-08,1,1
```

with

```
date,added,deleted
2016-01-11,91,9
2016-01-15,5,82
2016-01-20,6,85
```

so that I would receive a table with 5 columns (date, added1, deleted1, added2, deleted2) what would merge rows that represent the same date and put zeroes  if there is no match:

```
date,added1,deleted1,added2,deleted2
2016-01-11,0,0,91,9
2016-01-15,0,0,5,82
2016-01-20,16,10,6,85
2016-02-08,1,1,0,0
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{h=(NR==1?"1":"");a[$1]=$2 h FS $3 h;next} 
       $1 in a{h=(FNR==1?"2":"");print $1,a[$1],$2 h,$3 h;delete a[$1];next}
              {print $1,0,0,$2,$3}
           END{for(k in a) print k,a[k],0,0}' file1 file2

date,added1,deleted1,added2,deleted2
2016-01-11,0,0,91,9
2016-01-15,0,0,5,82
2016-01-20,16,10,6,85
2016-02-08,1,1,0,0
```

Update: header fixed.

Note that this is not an ordered merge, the output order follows file2 record order and any records in file1 only may be printed in different order.  If there is a natural order of the records pipe the output to `sort`.

Comment: hash only affects the unmatched records in the first file (leftovers after matching) and will be printed at the bottom, in this case there is only one.

Answer (score 1):

This will merge any number of files with any number of fields (assuming each file has the same number of fields), not just 2 files with 3 fields each:

```
$ cat tst.awk                
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 { hdrKey = $1 }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        vals[$1][ARGIND][i] = $i (FNR>1?"":ARGIND)
    }
}
END {
    prtRow(hdrKey)

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (date in vals) {
        prtRow(date)
    }
}
function prtRow(key,    val,fileNr,fieldNr) {
    printf "%s", key
    for (fileNr=1;fileNr<=ARGIND;fileNr++) {
        for (fieldNr=2;fieldNr<=NF;fieldNr++) {
            val = vals[key][fileNr][fieldNr]
            printf "%s%s", OFS, (val?val:0)
        }
    }
    print ""
    delete vals[key]
}

$ gawk -f tst.awk file1 file2
date,added1,deleted1,added2,deleted2
2016-01-11,0,0,91,9
2016-01-15,0,0,5,82
2016-01-20,16,10,6,85
2016-02-08,1,1,0,0
```

It uses GNU awk 4.* for ARGIND, multi-dimensional arrays and sorted array traversal.